# call struts action from jquery

Tags: jquery, struts

I am trying to call a struts1.3 action from jQuery .

I have tried this:

```
$.get("/samplAction.do",function(response){

//some code

});
```

But the action is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the misspelling of samplAcion.do is not your problem?

Answer (score 0):

how about withou "/" ?  because I do this:
having

```
$.post("add.do", $(this).serialize(), function(response){
//code
});
```

and my struts-config has this:

```
<action path="/something/add"
        type="com.xxxx.yyyy.zzzz"
        parameter="add"
        name="aForm"
        scope="request"
        input="major.page">
</action>
```